# Import Dart file in Android folder - Flutter

Tags: java, android, dart, flutter

I want to import a dart file from /lib folder to android/app/src/main/.../MainActivity.java file in my flutter project

How can I be able to achieve that?

I have tried this till yet, but it gives me "error: <(identifier)> expected"

```
import 'package:mypackage/model.dart';
```

Comment: You can not import dart file/code to your java file. They are 2 different languages.

Comment: What if I have to use that model here?

Comment: I am not sure why you need to use model in MainActivity. Can you explain your situation?

Comment: I have created models, pages etc in flutter. For the some particular case, I have to run some native android functionality, so for that, I need to use that model.

Comment: You have to implement the same model in Dart. In addition, you need to be able to encode/decode both models using just values that you can pass over a method channel, should you want to pass them back and forth. You might use JSON to encode/decode as a string, protobuf to bytes, or convert them to lists or maps of supported objects.

Comment: I have already said that I have created models in flutter i.e Dart, and yes I have mapping functionality as well. But that's not what I have asked here. I am asking something else.